# How do I set Properties for Seq in my appsettings.json file?

Tags: .net-core, appsettings, seq

In my seq logs there are no properties set and I couldn't find a way to set them via appsettings.json. I could set them with the method

.Enrich.WithProperty("App", "Absence Service")

but for dotnet core dependency injection I would prefer it to be set in the appsettings.json where it look like this:

```
"Seq": {
  "ServerUrl": "xxxx",
  "ApiKey": "xxxx",
  "MinimumLevel": "Warning",
  "LevelOverride": {
  "Microsoft": "Error"
  }
}
```

How do I set properties like for example the app or environment inside the appsettings.json?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the appsettings config values into your logger configuration when your application is starting up.

```
var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Seq(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Seq:ServerUrl"),
        apiKey: Configuration.GetValue<string>("Seq:ApiKey"),
        bufferBaseFilename: Configuration.GetValue<string>("Seq:BufferFilename"),
        controlLevelSwitch: levelSwitch);
```

Your config formatting looks like it would work just fine.